# Chrome Extension detect mouseover on context menu item

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, mouseover, right-click

Is it possible to detect the mouseover event on the custom context menu item added with 'chrome.contextMenus.create({...})'?

I want to kind of "preview" the action of the menu item when the user hovers their mouse over that menu item. So to do that I need to detect when the mouse is hovering over that item.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. The only event is `onClicked`, see the documentation.

Comment: Can you put that as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted